# handling JSON via play framework 1.2.3

Tags: json, playframework-1.x

I am sending a JSON message via XHR in a post request (content type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 - I am using firefox/chrome).
However, I am unable to process/receive the JSON message in the play 1,.2.3 controller -  probably due to pilot error.  Any insights/working example would be appreciated - thanks

JSON message (validates successfully in JSONLint):

```
{"email":"admin1@test.com","password":"admin123"}
```

Should I be looking at TypeBinder or create the object from the request parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up iterating through request.params.allSimple in order to get the value via request.params.get.  I used the JsonParser().parse on this value to get the JSONElement.  I then used getAsJsonObject() on the JSONElement to get the JSONBody.  I retrieved the needed JSONElements through a get call on the JSONBody & then a getAs method call to get to the actual value.  I will investigate TypeBinders in more detail - any other suggestions would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can use gson that is embedded in play to parse the param. In your controller method

```
MyParam myParam = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(request.params.get("myParam"), MyParam.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try using FLEXJSON (http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/) in order to avoid running into any circular loop errors, especially when